# Can't execute any command

Tags: linux, debian, hardware, kernel

I can't execute any command on my Debian server, for exammple if I try to execute "reboot" command I have this :

```
root@server002:~# reboot
-bash: /sbin/reboot: Input/output erro
```

Or if I want to create file via touch command :

```
root@server002:~# touch toto
touch: cannot touch `toto': Read-only file system
```

In /var/log/messages I can view this lines :

```
May 6 13:22:03 server002 kernel: ata1: hard resetting link
May 6 13:22:09 server002 kernel: ata1: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
May 6 13:22:10 server002 kernel: ata1: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
May 6 13:22:15 server002 kernel: ata1: hard resetting link
May 6 13:22:15 server002 kernel: ata1: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
May 6 13:22:20 server002 kernel: ata1: hard resetting link
May 6 13:22:20 server002 kernel: ata1: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
May 6 13:22:20 server002 kernel: ata1.00: disabled
May 6 13:22:25 server002 kernel: ata1: hard resetting link
```

I think there is a hardware problem with my hard disk, how can I be sure? What can I do?

Thank you

Comment: That looks like failed storage of some sort.  You may need to force a hardware reboot.  Good luck, and hope you have backups.

Comment: Either your disk or SATA controller is faulty, but before replacing them try to connect the drive to another port or try to use a different SATA cable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something wrong with your hardware - this can be the hard drive itself, the motherboard, or maybe the cable connection is noisy. Use badblocks to check the drive. But I suggest to back-up all the data beforehand, as comprehensive tests can kill a dying drive.

Comment: Also, check S.M.A.R.T. data.